# UITableView reloading behavior like Tweetbot/Twitter

Tags: uitableview, twitter, insert, scroll, reload

Does anybody know how to implement a UITableView like Tweetbot/Twitter. I want the TableView to insert the rows at the top instead of pushing the older rows down. 
I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279730/keep-uitableview-static-when-inserting-rows-at-the-top). However, I suppose that Tweetbot doesn't do it with a UIImage since the user is able to scroll while the TableView is reloading its stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use setContentOffset:animated: instead of tableView.animated =